# Misalignment in jasper report

Tags: report

[image]

[image]

If the content in the report continue to the second page then there is a misalignment in bottom of first page.
Check Threshold/Interval field in first page of the report.The line not printed correctly at the bottom of the report.

I have tried Stretch type to 'Relative to Tallest Object' for all the column but it is not work.
Can someone help on this issue?
JRXML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2016-06-13T04:56:24 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="amp" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="eefb61f0-0add-423d-bbab-2899bb0dffcf">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="unselfishFerret"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <template><![CDATA[new ByteArrayInputStream($P{STYLE_SHEET}.getBytes())]]></template>
    <parameter name="STYLE_SHEET" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="REPORT_TIME" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["1100"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="FOOTER_STRING" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="TITLE_STRING" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="PAGE_HEADER_STRING" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="SUB_FLEET_REPORT" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="AIRCRAFT_REPORT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="SAMPLE_FLEET_REPORT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="OASES_OPTION" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="OPERATOR_NAME" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="FLEET" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["A"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="REVISION_ID" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["441"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="INCL_SUB_FLEET" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="INCL_SAMPLE_FLEET" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="INCL_AIRCRAFT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="INCL_DIFF" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="INCL_PACKAGES" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="INCL_ACCESS_PANELS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="INCL_MAN_HOURS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="INCL_WORKCARD_NUMBER" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="WORKCARD_PROPERTIES" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="PACKAGES_REPORT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="DIFF_REVISION_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="AMP_DIFFERENCE_REPORT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="BLOCK_KEY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="GROUP_WORKCARD_SECTIONS" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="WORKCARD_SECTIONS" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="INCL_WC_NOSECTION" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="INCL_WORKCARD_PROPERTIES" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="INCL_TRADE" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="INCL_SKILL" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="INCL_ZONE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="INCL_SECTION_SUMMARY" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SECTION_REPORT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="INCL_MEN" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="INCL_SERIAL_LEVEL_CLL" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="INCL_ADSB_INTERVALS" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="DOCUMENT_CLASSES" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SUB_FLEET" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="AIRCRAFT_CODE" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="EFFECTIVE_CARDS_FILTER" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="INCL_HIGH_THRESH" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="INCL_PACKAGE_SUMMARY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM TABLE(AMP_REPORT_PKG.GET_AMP_REPORT($P{FLEET}, $P{REVISION_ID}, $P{INCL_SUB_FLEET}, $P{INCL_SAMPLE_FLEET}, $P{INCL_AIRCRAFT}, $P{INCL_DIFF},  $P{INCL_PACKAGE_SUMMARY} , $P{INCL_ACCESS_PANELS}, $P{INCL_MAN_HOURS},
$P{INCL_MEN},
$P{INCL_TRADE},
$P{INCL_SKILL},
$P{INCL_WORKCARD_NUMBER},
$P{INCL_WORKCARD_PROPERTIES},
$P{WORKCARD_PROPERTIES},
$P{BLOCK_KEY},
$P{GROUP_WORKCARD_SECTIONS},
$P{INCL_WC_NOSECTION},
$P{WORKCARD_SECTIONS},
$P{INCL_SECTION_SUMMARY},
$P{INCL_HIGH_THRESH},
$P{INCL_SERIAL_LEVEL_CLL},
$P{INCL_ADSB_INTERVALS},
$P{DOCUMENT_CLASSES},
$P{EFFECTIVE_CARDS_FILTER},
$P{SUB_FLEET},
$P{AIRCRAFT_CODE}
))]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ROW_TYPE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CHAPTER" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CHAPTER_DESCRIPTION" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="OPERATOR_CONTACT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="FLEET" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="FLEET_DESCRIPTION" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SUB_FLEET_DESCRIPTION" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AIRCRAFT_REG" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="REVISION" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="REVISION_DATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SCHEDULE_REFERENCE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ZONE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="DESCRIPTION" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PACKAGES" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ACCESS_PANELS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="THRESHOLD_INTERVAL" class="oracle.sql.CLOB"/>
    <field name="REFERENCE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LABOUR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="EFFECTIVITY" class="oracle.sql.CLOB"/>
    <field name="WORKCARD_NUMBER" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="WORKCARD_SECTION_CODE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="WORKCARD_SECTION_TITLE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="WORKCARD_SECTION_DESC" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SECTION_DEFINED" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="REPORT_TITLE" class="java.lang.String">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA["Aircraft Maintenance Programme"]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="WORKCARD SECTION" isStartNewPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$P{GROUP_WORKCARD_SECTIONS}.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") ? $F{WORKCARD_SECTION_TITLE} : null]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="20">
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="SubSectionTitle" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="5394ed8b-3345-4184-8be7-84a1613a78b2">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{ROW_TYPE}.equals("BODY") && $P{GROUP_WORKCARD_SECTIONS}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{SECTION_DEFINED} ? "" : "Section "  ) + ($F{WORKCARD_SECTION_CODE} ? $F{WORKCARD_SECTION_CODE} + " - " : "") + $F{WORKCARD_SECTION_TITLE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="50">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$F{ROW_TYPE}.equals("BODY_NO_DATA")]]></printWhenExpression>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <group name="CHAPTER TITLE" isStartNewPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{CHAPTER}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="20">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{ROW_TYPE}.equals("BODY")]]></printWhenExpression>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="SubSectionTitle" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="e4f1a264-a28b-4f86-8479-94d9da2f6e83">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{ROW_TYPE}.equals("BODY") && !$F{CHAPTER}.trim().equals("")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Chapter " + $F{CHAPTER} + " " + $F{CHAPTER_DESCRIPTION}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="CHAPTER" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{CHAPTER}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="24">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{ROW_TYPE}.equals("BODY") || $F{ROW_TYPE}.equals("BODY_NO_DATA")]]></printWhenExpression>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="98" y="0" width="204" height="24" uuid="33271916-3c9e-475b-a990-b05fefc27341">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_ZONE}.equals("N") && $P{INCL_PACKAGES}.equals("N")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Description]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="98" height="24" uuid="75c29c79-0771-48c9-ba46-55dd713d436d"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Task
Number]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="98" y="0" width="28" height="24" uuid="ad030728-aefe-4c01-82b9-63ffb8214ad3">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_ZONE}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Zone]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="126" y="0" width="144" height="24" uuid="f5bec4a3-9d5f-4fb3-b85f-7d1fe6b50ba1">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_PACKAGES}.equals("Y") && $P{INCL_ZONE}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Description]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="126" y="0" width="176" height="24" uuid="f3babdd8-5c03-480a-90c7-44946b2a7ce2">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_PACKAGES}.equals("N") && $P{INCL_ZONE}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Description]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="270" y="0" width="32" height="24" uuid="489f88e5-8fd9-41a2-afa1-b3f031a838f0">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_PACKAGES}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Packs]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="302" y="0" width="45" height="24" uuid="884c7a60-c6c5-4920-98d6-5c2b178cc80f">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_ACCESS_PANELS}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Access
Panels]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="347" y="0" width="145" height="24" uuid="c36ef99c-4cfc-4f37-a6fc-472af3a3678a">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_ACCESS_PANELS}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Threshold/Interval]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="302" y="0" width="190" height="24" uuid="489fa447-327f-4cee-9340-638c67ec15f7">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_ACCESS_PANELS}.equals("N")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Threshold/Interval]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="492" y="0" width="110" height="24" uuid="f37be1b1-7d61-4f2f-9153-a96eeb598ad7"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Reference(s)]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="673" y="0" width="101" height="24" uuid="acb38d7a-3f06-4ca4-ae09-27faaa17c2dc">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($P{INCL_MAN_HOURS}.equals("Y") || $P{INCL_TRADE}.equals("Y") || $P{INCL_MEN}.equals("Y")) && $P{INCL_WORKCARD_NUMBER}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Effectivity]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="602" y="0" width="200" height="24" uuid="0b0ab680-6410-4774-a78d-8652b861a9ea">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_MAN_HOURS}.equals("N") && $P{INCL_MEN}.equals("N") && $P{INCL_TRADE}.equals("N") && $P{INCL_WORKCARD_NUMBER}.equals("N")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Effectivity]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="602" y="0" width="172" height="24" uuid="4e767292-2e07-4caa-a6eb-d556a847fd73">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_MAN_HOURS}.equals("N") && $P{INCL_MEN}.equals("N") && $P{INCL_TRADE}.equals("N") && $P{INCL_WORKCARD_NUMBER}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Effectivity]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="673" y="0" width="129" height="24" uuid="356d2105-e6c4-468f-a983-7eab1fc5a5fc">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($P{INCL_MAN_HOURS}.equals("Y") || $P{INCL_TRADE}.equals("Y") || $P{INCL_MEN}.equals("Y"))  && $P{INCL_WORKCARD_NUMBER}.equals("N")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Effectivity]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="774" y="0" width="28" height="24" uuid="885bfb92-b6ab-4617-87d6-661428cc409a">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_WORKCARD_NUMBER}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Card]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="602" y="0" width="71" height="24" uuid="77f416ad-5def-4543-a0a8-561b39a5f139">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_MAN_HOURS}.equals("Y")  && $P{INCL_TRADE}.equals("N") && $P{INCL_MEN}.equals("N")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Hours]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="602" y="0" width="71" height="24" uuid="e967935f-2cdd-47a8-b0f9-cada8dd554cb">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_MAN_HOURS}.equals("N")  && $P{INCL_TRADE}.equals("N") && $P{INCL_MEN}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Men]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="602" y="0" width="71" height="24" uuid="9dd1b2c6-4dba-44d3-85bb-abd82f38ec1a">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_MAN_HOURS}.equals("Y")  && $P{INCL_TRADE}.equals("N") && $P{INCL_MEN}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Men/Hours]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="602" y="0" width="71" height="24" uuid="cf7d1e10-57cd-4fad-87ce-5cda585e6f7a">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_MAN_HOURS}.equals("N")
&& $P{INCL_TRADE}.equals("Y")
&& $P{INCL_MEN}.equals("N")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Trade]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="602" y="0" width="71" height="24" uuid="08ec06d6-5f9f-4e28-97d6-9972912a5f5f">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_MAN_HOURS}.equals("Y")  && $P{INCL_TRADE}.equals("Y") && $P{INCL_MEN}.equals("N")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Trade/Hours]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="602" y="0" width="71" height="24" uuid="b324f07d-8a66-403e-83c1-d500925594ae">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_MAN_HOURS}.equals("N")  && $P{INCL_TRADE}.equals("Y") && $P{INCL_MEN}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Trade/Men]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="602" y="0" width="71" height="24" uuid="4f598842-b6fc-425e-ba89-efd2778737ca">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_MAN_HOURS}.equals("Y")  && $P{INCL_TRADE}.equals("Y") && $P{INCL_MEN}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Trade/Men/ Hours]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="DetailBandTableTitle" mode="Opaque" x="98" y="0" width="172" height="24" uuid="517919f1-b95a-41ee-b330-f89ff7380d9a">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{INCL_ZONE}.equals("N") && $P{INCL_PACKAGES}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <text><![CDATA[Description]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="70" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="-21" y="0" width="843" height="26" uuid="fcd1da8b-d90a-44ac-8470-1241600d18df"/>
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_TITLE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_TITLE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_TIME">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_TIME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="PAGE_NUMBER">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="STYLE_SHEET">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{STYLE_SHEET}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="OPERATOR_NAME">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{OPERATOR_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="OASES_OPTION">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{OASES_OPTION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(
  new ByteArrayInputStream( $P{TITLE_STRING}.getBytes()))]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement style="HeaderBandTableTitle" positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="99" y="26" width="193" height="14" uuid="d5f7dfde-4c1e-4bf6-805b-809b7aae6566">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{AIRCRAFT_REG} == null && $F{SUB_FLEET_DESCRIPTION} == null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Fleet"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement style="HeaderBandTableTitle" positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="292" y="26" width="406" height="14" uuid="7ab0d393-8553-451c-bda0-5321671cd7a8"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Revision"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement style="HeaderBandTableText" positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="99" y="40" width="193" height="14" uuid="2f303c48-3657-42ba-8043-cc992f0d8d08">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{AIRCRAFT_REG} == null && $F{SUB_FLEET_DESCRIPTION} == null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FLEET_DESCRIPTION}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>



        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```